# Error During 16.04 Install "Can't display this video mode"

Tags: system-installation, video

Is there a means of editing the usb/disk image so I can set the screen resolution

My screen's optimum resolution is 1680x1050.

Comment: Do you have NVIDIA graphics?

Comment: It's an ATI Technologies Rage XL PCI, card in an old server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the future beginners out there....**

I was working on a server install for 16.04 my main issue was that after install, post reboot, I couldn't see the command line on screen. I believe one fix could have been getting a smaller screen, but I didn't have one.

I also setup the server as RAID 1, so my second issue was that I couldn't just boot into rescue mode from the install disk and edit grub, without figuring out how to mount a RAID 1 drive from rescue mode. It can be done, and I intend to learn but I'm a server/ubuntu beginner!

**My solution:**

1. Install from USB/CD - 
   I didn't connect the computer to a network, so DHCP failed, and instead it asked me to manually set IP, Gateway etc, which I did. DHCP may work - I don't know - but this is the way I did it. 
   When asked what options to install, I included **SSH**, as well as other items required, like **samba**.
2. When install completed I plugged it into my local network, confirmed the IP address on the network using **`netstat -r`, and using terminal (OSX) I logged into the server via SSH using.

   > `ssh denski@192.168.0.11`
3. Once logged in I type:

   > `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

and then removed the # from the following line to uncomment it: `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`

followed by `ctrl+x` to save and exit

Finally I ran the following to commands to update grub and reboot:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

I was then able to use the machine with a screen plugged in, rather than remotely. While also getting around the fact I was using RAID so couldn't easily get in via a rescue boot.

Hope this helps somebody!